# Disable superview from scrolling if subview is scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // initialize cell

    if let pickerCell = cell as? SettingsPickerCell {
        collectionView.panGestureRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(pickerCell.picker.collectionViewController.collectionView!.panGestureRecognizer)
    }

    return cell
}
```

The code above works, albeit is as ugly as hell. I have a scrollView buried deep in a view hierarchy, and I need a better way to disable the collection view scrolling when the picker is scrolling.

I tried using the `exclusiveTouch` property, didn't help. Is there a better way than this?

Comment: is this related to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26512396/758831)?

Comment: @wmorrison365 I don't think so, since my question is an answer to that OP. Also, the solution in looking for could be a better design pattern using the same idea I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way to subclass your collection view and override

```
func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
```

and other related methods. There you can control your touch flow and solve your issue.